# Installing LPSolve to MATLAB: "mxlpsolve.dll not found"

Tags: matlab, lpsolve

I'm trying to install lpsolve to use in MATLAB. I've followed the following instructions correctly.

> 1. Download an uncompress lp_solve_5.5.0.10_dev.zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/.
> 2. Copy lpsolve55.dll into the C:/WINDOWS/system32 directory or any other location that is in the Windows path for your computer.
> 3. Download an uncompress lp_solve_5.5.0.10_MATLAB_exe.zip from https://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/.
> 4. Copy the files included in the zip file to a directory that is in your Matlab path (for example the solvers subfolder under the main
>      COBRA Toolbox folder).
> 5. Test the lp_solve solver by entering mxlpsolve in the Matlab command window. If lp_solve libraries are correctly installed, you should see
>      usage instructions of the mxlpsolve interface.

**Problem:** When I run `mxlpsolve`, I get an error: `mxlpsolve.dll not found`

I am sure that the `mxlpsolve.dll` file exists and it is in the same path as `mxlpsolve.m`. Error gives me the list of paths that is searched and `mxlpsolve.dll` is **in** one of them.

I have tried to put `mxlpsolve.dll` into `C:\Windows\System32`. I have tried to install different versions of lpsolve. I have also tried to change `.dll` to `.mexw32` as recommended in forums but still failed.

[image: Screenshot of list of paths that is searched by command]

Comment: What is your Matlab version 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Mohammadnagdawi MATLAB R2018a 64-bit version.

Comment: Please try to install it with Matlab 32-bit